# Setting objects within the useState defined object

Tags: reactjs, redux

Creating a component for users to edit their listings

Scenario:
I have a defined listing object using useState and it gets set using useEffect after the listing is retrieved from the API, shown below:

```
const listing = useSelector((state) => state.listings.listing);
const [editListing, setEditListing] = React.useState({});

React.useEffect(() => {
    getListing(listingId)(dispatch);
    setEditListing(listing);
  }, []);
```

```
Ex Listing Obj

Listing = {
title: 'title'
description: 'something here'
location: { //having trouble setting these properly
   country:
   city:
   state:
},
etc..
}
```

I can set everything just fine except the listing.location. Using the form all inputs get filled with correct value, but when I change say just City input it sets listing.location.city and everything else goes blank. Here is how I am setting the listing.location object:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setEditListing((listing) => ({
      ...listing,
      location: { [name]: [value] },
    }));
  };
```

This should be the only code you need, I am pretty sure I am just not setting the location correct within the listing.

Comment: It would probably be worth seeing the code for your store and the dispatched action, but it looks like the issue is in your useEffect hook. Assuming that the initial state of listing in the store is null / undefined / empty object - in useEffect you are dispatching what must be an asynchronous function to fetch a listing, but you are not waiting for it to finish. On the next line you are immediately setting listing to the editListing state value - as the asynchronous action won’t have completed, you are setting the initial listing store value to state

Comment: @Chris I do wait for the call to come back in the action, the listing gets set fine with all the data from the API

Comment: In your handleChange function, inside the setEditListing call, before you return the new state value can you console.log the listing variable - most likely it’s undefined or empty

Comment: Also, in the useEffect, after the line where you call getListing, please can you console.log the listing variable

Comment: @Chris you are right, the object is blank when I try refreshing the edit listing page and console logging the listing. Can I use another useEffect for setting the editListing?

Comment: Yes you could have a separate useEffect hook that has the listing as a dependency and updates the edit state when the listing changes

Comment: @Chris Just did this and its working much better, thanks so much for that catch

Comment: @Chris still having the issue with setting the location object within the listing object. Whenever I set just one, say the country, then everything else disappears (only in the location object though).

Comment: Can you update the question with the changes you have made?

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the location object with a new object each time. Try spreading the location object:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setEditListing((listing) => ({
      ...listing,
      location: {
         ...listing.location,
         [name]: value
      }
    }));
  };
```

Note that I have removed the square brackets from value as I am assuming you don't want this to be an array

Comment: Yes I found another way that worked but this is exactly what I wanted thanks!! Still learning the object spreading stuff.

Comment: It’s definitely useful to learn how to do it, but I would also recommend you check out the use-immer npm package if you can add it to your project. Good luck!

Comment: Hey man, you ever have time for me to ask you some questions about using redux and managing state. Maybe connect on discord? just some small questions I have:)